# TWISTED Longest common subsequence

Tags: string, algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming, induction

I was wondering about a special case of the Longest Common Subsequence problem
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem
What if we have two strings of n symbols and its guaranteed that both of them have exactly 1 symbol and every symbol from the first n symbols of an alphabet.
How can the normal algorithm be improved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're asking for the longest common subsequence between permutations. There is an improvement over the dynamic programming one you linked called the Robinson-Schensted-Knuth algorithm, and it runs in time O(n lg n). There's a reasonably simple example of how it works [in Lectures 7 & 8 of this course](http://hamilton.nuigalway.ie/teachingWeb/CompMolBio/CompMolBiol.html), and a much more complete but involved explanation [here](http://www.math.ubc.ca/~cass/research/pdf/RS.pdf).